# Rails views and nill classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, haml, null

I'm outputting the user's First+Last name by using: `=current_user.try(:first_name)+" "+current_user.try(:last_name)`

However, if they're both nil, I get an error for trying to add a space between two nil values.

What's a better way to handle this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better keep the logic out of the view by moving the full name logic into the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def full_name
    [first_name, last_name].compact.join(' ')
  end
end
```

Then use it in your view:

```
= current_user.full_name
```